# texture(shadowMap, coords).xyzw always returns (1,1,1,1)

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, textures, shadow-mapping

I am attempting implementing shadows in my OpenGL scene. However, in my shader, whenever I try to access the texture value in the shadow map (that I rendered previously), I always get `1`, or a value close to `1`, for the `x`, `y`, `z`, and `w` values.

The problem is that I thought these values are supposed to represent the `z` coords of the respective fragment in the shadow map/texture (from the sun's perspective).

The relevant initiation code (in JOGL):

```
gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

// generate stuff
IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
gl.glGenFramebuffers(1, ib);
depthMapFBO = ib.get(0);

ib = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
gl.glGenTextures(1, ib);
depthMap = ib.get(0);

gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap);
gl.glTexImage2D(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL2.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 1024, 1024, 0, GL2.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL2.GL_FLOAT, null);
// prevents 'shadow acne'
gl.glPolygonOffset(2.5f, 0);
// prevents multiple shadows
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
// prevents (or expects!!!) pixel-y textures
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST);
// store one value in all four components of pixel
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE, GL2.GL_INTENSITY);
```

The relevant draw/per-frame code:

```
// render shadows
gl.glUseProgram(shadowProgram);

gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(lightMatrixLocShadow, 1, false, lightMatrix.getMatrix(), 0);  // yep (haha change viewMatrix -> lightMatrix)
gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(projMatrixLocShadow, 1, false, projMatrix.getMatrix(), 0);

gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
gl.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL2.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, sha.depthMap, 0);
gl.glDrawBuffer(GL2.GL_NONE);
gl.glReadBuffer(GL2.GL_NONE);
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

gl.glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 1024);
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
gl.glClear(GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
renderScene(gl, sunMatrix);
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

// render display (regular)
gl.glUseProgram(displayProgram);
gl.glDrawBuffer(GL2.GL_FRONT);
gl.glReadBuffer(GL2.GL_FRONT);

gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrixLoc, 1, false, viewMatrix.getMatrix(), 0);
gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(projMatrixLocDisplay, 1, false, projMatrix.getMatrix(), 0);
gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(lightMatrixLocDisplay, 1, false, lightMatrix.getMatrix(), 0);
gl.glUniform4fv(sunPositionLoc, 1, sunWorldPosition, 0);    // send sun's position to shader
gl.glUniform1f(sunBrightnessLoc, sunBrightness);
gl.glUniform1i(shadowMapLoc, 0);

gl.glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
//gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
// day-night cycle
float[] color = SkyManager.getSkyColor(time);
gl.glClearColor(color[0], color[1], color[2], 1);
gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glActiveTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE0);
gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, sha.depthMap);
//gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
renderScene(gl, sunMatrix);
```

The relevant fragment shader code (used to debug the values; in glsl 1.3)

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(texture2D(shadowMap, lightProjPosition.xy).z), 1.0);
```

The expected values from the `texture()` call are, of course, the different distances of the fragments to the light source.
If anyone can find out why I am getting `1` I would appreciate the help.

**EDIT**

Here is the shadow shader code:

Vertex:

```
#version 130

uniform mat4 light;
uniform mat4 proj;

out vec4 position;

void main() {
    position = proj * light * gl_Vertex;
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 130

in vec4 position;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor.z = position.z;    // still doesn't work with this line commented
}
```

Comment: I don't see how you expect to get anything other than white when writing the depth value to 8 bit colors.

Comment: @derhass Can you explain more?

Comment: what makes you so sure it is returning 1.0 as opposed to say 0.9995 or 0.9991?

Comment: I added in the post, some of the fragments are a little darker than pure white, and I just found out that sometimes, some fragments are black!

Comment: So what is your question then? Slightly gray sounds perfectly fine for a logarithmic depth buffer.

Comment: Here is a screenshot. Notice how it is black on top and white on bottom. https://img42.com/8rKS4

Comment: Sometimes it is all white/light grey. Other times it is black (on top) and white (beneath that). Also, there is a white line that is rendered on the ZY plane that is relative to the light matrix. The light matrix rotates, and the white line is always on the ZY plane relative to the matrix. Also, when I render normally (with shadows rendered dark; without that debugging line of GLSL), all the world in `-z` (relative to the light matrix) is dark and everything in `+z` is light.

Comment: You are getting exactly what you should get (as far as one could tell). So what is the problem?

Comment: I think I am supposed to get numbers close to 0 (showing up black) for fragments close to the light source and higher numbers (showing up white) for fragments far away from the light source.

Comment: Well, you assumption is misguided. You do get black for fragments very close to the light source. But the keyword here is "very". You have not specified the parameters of your projection matrix, but for the values typically chosen, you will get > 0.99 for practically everything, except stuff literally touching the light source.

Comment: Good point, but as I said, when I use this value to compare with the `z` value of the fragment, I get one side of the world lit and the other side immersed in shadow. I don't get real shadows.

Comment: Just to be clear, I get values that are white, and when I subtract 1.0 from then they are black in the fragment shadow.

Comment: Well, your still barking at the wrong tree. The values are correct. Trying to visualize 24 or 32 bit precision in just 8 bit colors will not work, no matter if everything gets just rounded to 1, or if it gets rounded to 0 - you will see nothing of interest either way.